# React Native 0.61 still requires me to link native modules

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-cli

Recently I have upgraded to a version of React Native which is `>=0.60`. From the [release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60) I can now see Native modules are "autolinked". So there is no need to use `react-native link` every time I want to install a library which uses native modules.

However, even after updating to the latest version of react native and unlinking all my modules. React Native would **not** auto-link them.

For example, I have just downloaded [React Native Slider](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-slider) and ran `npm install @react-native-community/slider --save`. After running `pod install` the required native module is never installed. Pod install does not install it in the terminal. And upon starting, my app would crash with the following error:

[image]

However, if I write `react-native link @react-native-community/slider` and then run `pod install` - I can see in the terminal that `pod` is installing the required native module of the library. The app would then start and will work properly.

Why does React Native not auto-link my modules so that pod can install them? My environment is the following:

```
react-native: 0.61.2
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react: 16.10.2
Xcode version: 11.1
iOS simulator version: 13.1
Pod version: 1.7.5
```

Comment: Just being curious: do you have `# Add new pods below this line` in _Podfile_?

Comment: @zvona No, I do not. Which ones should I have there by default?

Comment: Same problem for me on Linux/Android

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this ? I am facing the same problem. Every time I install a new library I have to run ```react-native link <lib>``` even though the library installation instructions mention it should not be required for react native >= 0.60

Comment: @sushrut619 Unfortunately, I did not find a solution. I had to create a new React Native project and migrate my components to it. It was a long and exhausting process but it was worth it!